# How to create if/elseif/if statement within dictionary - Python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am quite new to Python. Trying to create an if/elseif/if in a dictionary in Python but cannot get it to work. Any suggestions?

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?token=APIKEY&expand=venue&location.latitude=55.676097&location.longitude=12.568337&location.within=5km&page=1')

data = response.json()

eventbrite = data["events"]

# create empty dictionaries
venuesToBeInserted = []

# insert venues to dictionary
for venue in eventbrite:
    venuesToBeInserted.append({
        'sourceID' : venue['venue']['id'],
        'name': venue['venue']['name'],
        'address': {
            'streetName' : 
            if venue['venue']['address']['address_1'] != None & venue['venue']['address']['address_2'] != None: 
                venue['venue']['address']['address_1'] + ' ' venue['venue']['address']['address_2'] 
            elif:
                venue['venue']['address']['address_1'] != None : venue['venue']['address']['address_1']
            else:
                None

            ,
            'ZipCode' : venue['venue']['address']['postal_code'],

        }
    })
```

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: I am not sure about the correct syntax for doing a if/elseif/else statement within a dictionary. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: `if/elif/else` and yes. But I'm not sure what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If in dict is used a little bit different

```
for venue in eventbrite:
venuesToBeInserted.append({
    'sourceID' : venue['venue']['id'],
    'name': venue['venue']['name'],
    'address': {
        'streetName': venue['venue']['address']['address_1'] + ' ' + venue['venue']['address']['address_2']
        if venue['venue']['address']['address_1'] != None & venue['venue']['address']['address_2'] != None
        # elif venue['venue']['address']['address_1'] != None : venue['venue']['address']['address_1']
        else None,
        'ZipCode' : venue['venue']['address']['postal_code'],
    }
})
```